# See variables environments in compilate project Angular 7.3.10

Tags: angular

In my project angular in producction (project compilated), i can see global variables for my browser, i wish can't see this variables, because i have urls bases for my application.

Tha globals variables in angular:

route angular/environments/environment.ts

export const environment = {
production: true,
api_url: 'XXXX',
url_app: 'XXX'
};

in browser:

[image]

Comment: Is this firebase config ?

Comment: in my case not but there you can also configure firebase in environments variables angular

Comment: Because, anything you provide client side is visible at client side, so that your config is visible at client side